# Symfony2 - Change encoders for existing users

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, passwords, password-hash

If you have an existing code base with users and their passwords, how can you change the password encoder and have users' passwords update?

In other words, let's say all user passwords are in MD5 and you want to transition to PBKDF2. The common strategy is to simply re-hash the password whenever the user logs in next.

However, I'm not sure how to do this in Symfony. Would it be done in the login controller? Or is there a way to do it in the EncoderInterface object?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this blog... seems like this is what you're looking for...

[How to change the way Symfony2 encodes passwords](http://www.ens.ro/2012/07/25/how-to-change-the-way-symfony2-encodes-passwords/)

You need to extend MessageDigestPasswordEncoder class, overwrite its methods and copy that class to the Security folder in your bundle (create one if not exist)
Check out the following example of how to extend MessageDigestPasswordEncoder

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder as      BaseMessageDigestPasswordEncoder;

class MessageDigestPasswordEncoder extends BaseMessageDigestPasswordEncoder
{
    private $algorithm;
    private $encodeHashAsBase64;

    public function __construct($algorithm = 'sha512', $encodeHashAsBase64 = true, $iterations = 5000)
    {
        $this->algorithm = $algorithm;
        $this->encodeHashAsBase64 = $encodeHashAsBase64;
        $this->iterations = $iterations;
    }

    protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
    {
        if (empty($salt)) {
            return $password;
        }

        return $salt.$password; // or do whatever you need with the password and salt
    }

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        // this is the original code from the extended class, change it as needed

        if (!in_array($this->algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('The algorithm "%s" is not supported.', $this->algorithm));
        }

        $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
        $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

        // "stretch" hash
        for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; $i++) {
            $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
        }

        return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) :  bin2hex($digest);
    }
}
```

After you have your class ready update your config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
# ...

parameters:
    security.encoder.digest.class: Ens\TestBundle\Security\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
```

Comment: It's not clear from this answer whether Symfony will automatically handle the asker's specific situation: transitioning from one password encoding to another, with existing stored passwords.  Symfony config lets you change the encoder easily enough, but what will happen next time the user logs in is not described.  Ideally the chosen encoding would have been stored in the user record, so it could decode the old way until it's updated, and then encode the new way on password reset (which could be triggered early by the app).  Does it do that?

Comment: The asker asked from where this should be done in Symfony "Would it be done in the login controller? Or is there a way to do it in the EncoderInterface object?" and not how, he knows how since he described the common way of doing such. The answer describe from were and how to do the re-hash in Symfony only.

Comment: From what I can tell, there is an EncoderAwareInterface, so it is possible to have the encoder based on the given User object. The real question is where the appropriate location for putting the update logic is, i.e., rehashing the password into the new format.